# Is there a way to stop my circle avatar from scaling over the x axis when having a background image

Tags: flutter

I added a circle avatar to my page with a background image. But I can't stop it from scaling over the x axis when I add the background image. When I don't have a background image but just a background color it's just perfectly round but when I do add one I get the following

[image]

When I wrap it in a sized box. If I don't it instead stretches. But it should just be a circle. What can I do to make it a circle?

```
    class _TheProfilePageState extends State<TheProfilePage> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
          body: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Stack(
                    children: 
                    [
                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                        child: NavigatePopButton(),
                      ),
                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                        child: Text
                        (
                          'Profile',
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 2,
                  child: SizedBox
                  (
                    width: 50.0,
                    height: 50.0,
                    child: CircleAvatar
                    (
                      backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/pictures/profile_placeholder.png'),
                      radius: 75,
                      foregroundColor: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 2,
                  child: ListView.separated
                  (
                    itemCount: 2,
                    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Divider(height: 1.0), 
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index)
                    {
                      return 
                      [
                        ListTile
                        (
                          title: Text(
                            'Name',
                            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
                          ),
                          trailing: Icon
                          (
                            Icons.edit,
                            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                          ),
                        ),
                        ListTile
                        (
                          title: Text(
                            'Phone Number',
                            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1,
                          ),
                          trailing: Text(
                            '0612345678',
                            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ][index];
                    }
                  )
                ),
              ],
            ),
        )
        );
      }

}
```

Comment: Did you try removing `Expanded` widget and then remove the  `SizedBox` ?

Comment: Yes I did actually gave similar results, I'll try again nowq

Comment: If that doesn't work, try removing width and height constraints from the `SizedBox`. But I think removing the Expanded widget should work.

Answer (score 0):

To make it a circle, you may use `ClipRRect` widget as a child of `CircleAvatar`. Working sample code below:

```
Expanded(
                flex: 2,
                child: SizedBox
                  (
                  width: 50.0,
                  height: 50.0,
                  child: CircleAvatar
                    (
                      child: ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(75),
                        child: Image.asset('assets/placeholder.png')
                      ),
                    foregroundColor: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Which looks like below in UI:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: The problem is that if I increase the size of the avatar the picture doesn't take the full space of the avatar which give it a huge border with the background color. But it is round tho.